# bad http authentication header format auth0 asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication, auth0

I am using auth0 with ASP.NET for roles and permission implementation. I want to fetch all users details by using auth0 api. Below is my code,

Code 1:

```
var apiClient = new ManagementApiClient("Bearer <<Token>>", new Uri("<<URL>>"));
var allClients = await apiClient.Clients.GetAllAsync();
```

Code 2:

```
var client = new ManagementApiClient("Authorization: Bearer <<Token>>", new Uri("<<URL>>"));
IPagedList<User> users = await client.Users.GetAllAsync();
```

Above both code giving me error:

> "bad http authentication header format auth0 asp.net"

tried same token and url in postman, And it's returning result,
Where I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [usage documentation](https://github.com/auth0/auth0.net#usage) for the `ManagementApiClient` class, the constructor receives just the token, so you should be calling it like:

```
new ManagementApiClient("<<Token>>", new Uri("<<URL>>"));
```

It will then automatically include that token in an HTTP `Authorization` header using the `Bearer` scheme.

Comment: May be your solution solved that error, But now it's saying "{"Query validation error: 'Invalid value \"v2/clients?include_fields=true\"' on property search_engine (Use 'v2' if you want to try our new search engine)."}"

Comment: The same docs mention that the URL should be something like `new Uri("https://YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN/api/v2")`. The `users`/`clients` path components will be automatically added depending on the call you're executing.

Comment: Thanks for sharing document path, I created one token including User:Read, and now it's giving me this error : "Path validation error: 'String does not match pattern ^.+\|.+$: users' on property id (The user_id of the user to retrieve)."